# Search textbox seen in agSetColumnFilter when we have just 2 options

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

We are looking to implement functionality and didn’t find documentation for achieving this part, let me explain.
We have an **Ag grid react** side filter being implemented in one of our screens, what we want to achieve is.

> Problem:

when we have **agSetColumnFilter** for many of our columns, as a part of this we have some columns,
Where the value is either 0 or 1 **( Just 2 Options )**, when this gets rendered has **agSetColumnFilter** it also comes with
A search filter textbox, but when we just have 2 options in the checklist, we are trying to get rid of the search textbox.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

set suppressMiniFilter = true

{
filter :'agSetColumnFilter',
filterParams : {
suppressMiniFilter: true,
...
}
}